# Is there any free GUI based sql data manipulation tool for people who do not know sql?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

A friend of mine has a MS SQL database installed. He wanted to be able to do insert and update (mostly these two operations) entries to some tables. But he has no idea how to use select, from, where.

I am wondering if there is a GUI for people like him, where you can specify conditions by clicking, or choosing something from drop-down list, and click a button, so that the SQL statement is generated and executed and the result of the query is shown in that GUI.

Comment: Why would you want a tool that displays the resulting SQL statement if the user is defined to be one who does not understand SQL? Or did I get the "and show the result in that GUI" phrase wrong?

Comment: @TheBlastOne sorry, I meant the result from the sql. The whole point is so that the user does not need to deal with SQL statement and can see the query result by using his mouse.

Comment: K, I see. Often, the only practical (i.e. on the long run efficient) way to supply such users with the functionality they need without making them IT "experts" at all was to create a custom GUI for manipulating the data. Consequently, in may organizations, there is one guy hanging around just creating and maintaining such specialized frontends (either by implementing them directly, or by customizing some frontend tool). Seems to be worth the trouble. A good editor is worth thousands of productive hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage MS SQL databases from a linked MS Access file. It has great visual tools. Check this out: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/connect-an-access-project-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-adp-HP005274586.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server Management Studio (available as an Express edition) has a menu option of "Edit Top 200 Rows" when you right-click on a table in the Object Explorer. If no-one else comes up with anything, it might be a starting point, depending on the size of the tables. You could also point him at the Database > Views > Right-Click > "New View" menu option as the UI is fairly similar to that which I recall from Access.

Access can also be used to access Sql Server data and I believe that the query builder in that is fairly friendly, although it's been a *long* time since I used it.

Comment: Glad you pointed out Access. Not very developper friendly, but it gets the job done nicely.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL, the views designer is a GUI that allows you to specify your columns, filters, "add group by" and more. The result is an SQL string that is automatically generated and updated for each operation you perform in the GUI. In your database, just go to views and create a new view.

However, I don't think you can see the view result without saving it (but that may not be a problem).

Comment: If I change something in the view, does it update the database instance?

Comment: The view is (more or less) a named select that you can use as a fake table. Unless you save your changes, the database will not be modified in any way. If you add a new view, you can simply delete it afterwards. As for changing rows in your table, that's not really possible as views can only perform SELECT queries.

Answer (score 0):

Hey. [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) also contains a feature where you can right-click on any table and then click "Script Table As". After that you have the option to get standard SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT statements on that table. You can script it out to a new query editor window or to the clipboard. Then you just edit the query to fill in the blanks. For example, if I script a table as insert, I see items like this:

`<ServiceContract, varchar(200),>`

This is telling me that I need to provide a value for this field and that the field expects a variable length string with a max of 200. Rob also pointed out that you can use the "Edit top 200 Rows" feature to edit the table data without even needing TSQL. It depends on whether you really want to generate the TSQL or not.

Answer (score 0):

For just basic read / write of a single table, I have to agree with @AppDev.  SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE are extremely easy statements to write and make a lot of sense logically.  Most of his statements would be just one short line of code.

I'd highly advise just showing him typical syntax of those statements.  It takes less time to learn that then any GUI you'll find.

```
SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM table_name

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)

UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2 WHERE some_column=some_value
```

It really is as simple as that, he can use SQL Management Server to view the tables, and then just fill in the blanks of those comands above.

(From http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)